# Redirecting / to /index.html in NancyFX

Tags: c#, nancy

I'm serving static content in a self-hosted Nancy and have overridden the root path, and also added a static content convention to redirect / to Content in my custom bootstrapper like so:

```
conventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("/", "Content"));
```

This works fine when requesting a URL like http://localhost/index.html but I would like http://localhost to redirect to index.html. This doesn't seem to work by default though. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps just redirect to index.html from the Get["/"] in the home module?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. I was trying to avoid using a module just for this; I was hoping it could be configured somehow!

Comment: Not that I'm aware of but I've never really gotten into that so I don't know for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this with a simple module like so:

```
public class IndexModule : NancyModule
{
    public IndexModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = _ => Response.AsFile(Settings.Instance.GetFullContentPath("index.html"));
    }
}
```

`Settings.Instance.GetFullContentPath` is my own method which returns a full path on disk to the specified file.

Answer (score 2):

Nancy will discover and auto-hook any IRequestStartup classes. Just create a class like this, and all will be fine :) (super-duper)

```
public class RootRedirector : IRequestStartup
{
    public void Initialize(IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Url.Path == "/")
        {
           throw new RouteExecutionEarlyExitException(new RedirectResponse("/index.html"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't like using exceptions for non-exceptional cases though! :)